# Hadoop process file with different field delimiters

Tags: mapreduce, hive, apache-pig

What are the options to process a text file with different field delimiters in the same file and non new line row delimiter?
Some fields in the file can be fixed length and some can be separated by a character.

> Example:
>   100  xyz      |abc@hello#200  xyz1     |abc1@world

In this example, 100 is the first field value, xyz is the second field value, abc is the 3rd field value, hello is the fourth field value. | and @ are the delimiters for the 3rd and the 4th fields. The lines are separated by #.

Any of Map reduce or pig or hive solution is fine.

One option may be an MR to configure a custom row delimiter, read the entire line and process the same. But any InputFormat accepts a custom delimiter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the record delimiter and set it to #.After that load the records as a line and then replace the '|' and '@' characters with space.Then you will get all the fields separated by ' '.Use STRSPLIT to get the individual fields.

```
SET textinputformat.record.delimiter '#'

A = LOAD 'data.txt' AS (line:chararray);
B = FOREACH A REPLACE(REPLACE(line,'|',' '),'@',' ') AS line;-- Note:'\\|' if you need to escape '|'
C = FOREACH B GENERATE STRSPLIT(line,' ',4);
DUMP C;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try Hive with RegexSerDe